# numpy.gradient specifying axes (central difference method)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am currently using version 1.92 of numpy which I believe is the latest publicly available one. I wish to use the central difference method quickly on an n dimensional array and specify an axis over which to perform the calculation.

My first thought was to use numpy.diff which allows axis specification, however this returns a right difference rather than a central difference and has limited functionality.

I understand the following method works using numpy.gradient

```
num_vectors=10 #number of 3-vectors in the 2D array
vectorarray=numpy.empty((num_vectors,3)) 
vectorarray[0]=[4,5,6]
vectorarray[1]=[1,4,4]
vectorarray[2]=[8,8,1] #add some arbitrary data for illustrative purposes

c1,c2=numpy.gradient(vectorarray)
```

So c1 stores the useful information that I require. The problem is that I also have to generate c2, and I want to do this sort of calculation with many dimensional arrays and will incur a time loss by generating all this useless data.

Is there any other method I can achieve this same result without the redundancy, preferably this also includes using nested for loops.

Comment: Tip: You can do `vectorarray[:3] = [[4,5,6],[1,4,4],[8,8,1]]` (with additional newlines and other whitespace as needed).

Comment: Newest is 1.10.1, not 1.9.2.

Comment: Can you give the formula for what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can read Numpy's gradient code at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1119 and use the algorithm therein.

You can also copy it and change [`for i, axis in enumerate(axes):`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1253) to `for i, axis in [[0,0]]:` so that it only runs once, but keep in mind that your modified code may fall under [Numpy's license](http://www.numpy.org/license.html).